# Export Mac app using openssl 1.0.1j

Tags: xcode, dynamic, embedded-resource, libssl

I have just begin develop app for Mac.

Now I have problem with exporting application using latest openssl.

1. I'm download and make for ".a" and ".dylib" file.
2. I import it to XCode project.
3. It runs on my MAC-PC ok. But when I export app for another MAC-PC.
   because: `bug library not loaded: /usr/local/..../libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`
4. I try to use run script:

   EXECFILE=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}

   install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib 'path to lib'/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
   install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib 'path to lib'/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

   TARGETID=`otool -DX 'path to lib'/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib`
   NEWTARGETID=@executable_path/../Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
   install_name_tool -change ${TARGETID} ${NEWTARGETID} ${EXECFILE}

   TARGETID1=`otool -DX 'path to lib'/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`
   NEWTARGETID1=@executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
   install_name_tool -change ${TARGETID1} ${NEWTARGETID1} ${EXECFILE}.

I certainly add copy file to frameworks and set run search path to.

5. But finally, it still show library not loaded, like this:

   Dyld Error Message:
     Library not loaded: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
     Referenced from: 'path to app'/Contents/Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
     Reason: image not found

Can anyone help me solve it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm apparently solve this problem:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc -shared --openssldir="@rpath"
```

After building app I add result dylibs to **Frameworks** folder, and modify application binary via install_name_tool:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib\
 ../Frameworks/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib BinaryName

install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib\
 ../Frameworks/libssl.1.0.0.dylib BinaryName
```

[Bash script](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Zifix/88ny/)